# Minus in w3c specification grammar

Tags: xml, specifications, w3c

What does the minus sign mean?

```
[14]    CharData ::= [^<&]* - ([^<&]* ']]>' [^<&]*)
```

From [the w3c XML 1.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-cdsection)

Also, where can I find information related to the syntax grammar?  I'm having troubling finding the specification about the specification, if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Minus**  (`-`) is part of the [Extended Backus-Naur Form (EBNF) notation](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-notation) used by the [W3C XML Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/) to define the formal grammar of XML:

- Minus (`-`) in `A - B` *matches any string that matches A but does
  not match B*.

### How to interpret the [`CharData`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-CharData) production

> `[14] CharData ::= [^<&]* - ([^<&]* ']]>' [^<&]*)`

- `[^<&]*` is a string of any characters except the markup start characters, `<` and `&`.
- `']]>'` is a literal string that is used to mark the end of [CDATA](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-cdata-sect).
- `([^<&]* ']]>' [^<&]*)` is any string without `<` and `&` that
  doesn't contain the end marker for a CDATA section.

Therefore, altogether, `CharData` can be ***any string that doesn't contain the markup start characters, `<` and `&`, and doesn't contain the CDATA end marker, `]]>`.***

### See also

- [Understanding XML CharData EBNF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64813063/290085)

Comment: Thanks so much.  The authors decided to wait until the end, rather than the beginning to describe the grammar of the document........ (Section 6, Notation)