# Understanding XML CharData EBNF

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, w3c

The following EBNF rule expressed as

```
CharData ::= [^<&]* - ([^<&]* ']]>' [^<&]*)
```

is really hard for me to understand. Can someone give a few examples of valid and invalid strings. A brief explanation of the what is being expressed in the rule would also be very helpful. Although perhaps asking a little much. It would also be ultra nice if you have an interesting snippet of c++ code lying around that'll help catch this occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EBNF production for [`CharData`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-CharData),

> `[14] CharData ::= [^<&]* - ([^<&]* ']]>' [^<&]*)`

means that XML character data can consist of any characters except

- `<`, which begins markup (tags, comments, XML declarations, CDATA sections, and PIs)
- `&`, which begins entity references,
- the string of characters, `]]>`, which ends a CDATA section.

**Escaping:**

- Escape `<` as `&lt;` in character data.
- Escape `&` as `&amp;` in character data.
- `]]>` cannot appear in character data; there is no escaped form.

**See also:**

- [Minus in w3c specification grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44955763/290085)

Comment: Thank you friend. For taking the time to answer my question. Although the specifications explanation was written in English. It felt like I was trying to read something a martian wrote. I just couldn't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Both regex (`[^<&]*`) and EBNF are indeed languages in their own right and are wonderfully expressive for specifying syntax.  Kudos to you for diving so deep to understand the specification.